# Android - creating a "to next page" button

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, onclicklistener

i have this code but every time i run the app and click on my button it crashes and i don't get why.. am i doing something wrong here any help would be great thanks

im trying to got to the "Sec.class" page/class

```
public class APPcalendarActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
        continueButton.setOnClickListener( (OnClickListener) this);
    }

    //@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.continue_button:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Sec.class);
            startActivity(i);           
            break;
        }

    }
```

THIS IS WHAT I WAS MISSING IN THE MANISFEST.XML FILE

and i want to slap the person who downgraded my question

```
 <activity android:name=".Sec"
android:label="@string/sec" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you've declared an `<activity>` tag for the `Sec` activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

But posting (or simply reading) the crash stacktrace from `logcat` would be more instructive.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the error is, it is really hard to guess what the problem is, but usually when this happens, the button (`continueButton` in your case) could not be found in the layout. So make sure that you have a View with id `continue_button` in `main.xml`.